# Timeline in choreograph going back to original position

Tags: pepper, choregraphe

I am trying to lift pepper's arms by using a timeline and then I physically move them with the animation mode to my desired position. Only one action and the arms move, however I cannot manage to leave the arms lifted. How should this be done?

[image: stifness]

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You have the right intuition by checking the resources, but sadly they do not interfere with Pepper's autonomous movements. This is a known issue.

Nonetheless are several ways to achieve this:

- Make a timeline box with the desired position as the first key frame, and running at 0 fps. You can set that [here](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-1/software/choregraphe/panels/timeline_panel.html#timeline-properties).
- Make a timeline box with your movement, and with a [behavior layer](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-1/software/choregraphe/panels/timeline_panel.html#choregraphe-reference-box-behavior-layer) at the end that loops the end of your movement using a `Go To` box, targeting the desired key frame.
- Disable [autonomous movements](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-1/naoqi/motion/autonomousmoves-api.html?highlight=autonomous#ALAutonomousMovesProxy::setBackgroundStrategy__ssCR). The robot will not automatically go back to a neutral resting position anymore.

Note that keeping the arms lifted leads to heating the shoulder motors fast.
When it gets close to overheating, the power in the shoulders is reduced, and so the arms may fall despite your command. Yes, Pepper gets physically tired like us!

Comment: I ended up doing a timeline but not at 0fps otherwise the movement is too fast so it is at 30. Then I just loop the box to keep the arms up. I am also doing the same program but using python. However, I haven't managed to achieve the same so I am combining choreograph to lift its arms and the SDK to do all the rest (tablet, move to, sockets)